# Riemannian metric inverse matrix

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I have an immersion $F: M\to\mathbb R^{n+1}$ with an n-dimensional smooth manifold. The coefficients of the metric $g$ are defined by $g_{ij}(p)=\left\langle \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}(p), \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_j}(p) \right\rangle, p\in M$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the standard scalar product on $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

How can I calculate the coefficients of the inverse matrix $\{g^{ij}\}=\{g_{ij}\}^{-1}$?

Thanks for any help

Comment: How about the usual formula for the inverse matrix, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/991996/2002)? Or, you have plenty of choices from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix).

Comment: But there is no "explicit" formula for the matrix elements? For fixed n one can find this, but in general?